# How to structure send email to all users using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, heroku

I plan to send my users a reminder email once a day.

I will user Heroku scheduler.

As I understand it:

I create a RAKE task in lib/tasks/scheduler.rake

Then do the config on Heroku to run that

In the RAKE task I need to call something like User.send_reminders, in send_reminders I pass a request to the mailer to send an email to each user.

My question is should send_reminders be in the the users model or the users controller?

Probably very basic but I can't quite work it out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always need to write model related actions in the model itself.
Controller should be kept percise for request related decision making.

So keep your send_reminders in model and call it from rake task.